How to add duplicate criteria for advanced filter?
I have an advanced filter that takes in a lot of data, and sometimes the data is the same product, just with a different date or price.
Example of what the advanced filter shows

The idea would be that the advanced filter looks through and finds which ones have the same product, person, supplier PN, and MOQ. Compares the rows that have these duplicates, can takes the one that has a more recent price update.
Shows which the duplicates and deleting the older duplicate

Is there a way for the advanced filter to do this?
I have a method already, however it is very slow and takes a long time:
Dim xRow As Integer, cRow As Integer, i As Integer
xRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 12 To xRow
For cRow = i + 1 To xRow
If Range("B" & cRow) = Range("B" & i) Then
    If Range("C" & cRow) = Range("C" & i) Then
        If Range("E" & cRow) = Range("E" & i) Then
            If Range("I" & cRow) = Range("I" & i) Then
            Range("B" & cRow & ":J" & cRow).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
Next cRow
Next i


For Each GreenRow In Range("Search!$B$12:$B$" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        If GreenRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
            Range("B" & GreenRow.Row).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Interior.Color <> vbGreen
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
            Loop
        End If
Next GreenRow

With this code, there is a long pause between the green coloring and the deleting of the rows.

You sould try to load you range in to a matix and manipulate the data that way. That is much quicker that adressing cells in the sheet. Here is an example
not related to your code, on how to load your range in to a matix and how to manipulate it:
Sub LoadRangeIntoMatrix()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim dataMatrix As Variant
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim colCount As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

    ' Define the range to be loaded into the matrix
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A1:C10") ' Change the range as needed

    ' Load the range into a 2-dimensional array (matrix)
    dataMatrix = dataRange.Value

    ' Get the number of rows and columns in the matrix
    rowCount = UBound(dataMatrix, 1)
    colCount = UBound(dataMatrix, 2)

    ' Example: Print the matrix data to the Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
    For i = 1 To rowCount
        For j = 1 To colCount
            Debug.Print "Row " & i & ", Column " & j & ": " & dataMatrix(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


I had no idea matrixes existed, it really is a lot faster like that!

@KittyLila Glad I could help you. It is really several magnitudes better.

Please, try the next code. It should be very fast even for large ranges, using a Dictionary (keeping only unique keys) and some arrays. All processing is done in memory. It returns the processed result (without the duplicate rows) in another sheet. In the example code, the next one, so such an empty sheet must exist after the one to be processed. Of course, you can use a sheet you want, but set it correctly. You can at the end to clear all existing sheet content and drop the final array content in the same sheet. I used two sheets in order to have the possibility to check the result without jeopardizing of the existing data...:
Sub ExtractUpdatedPrice()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrKey, arrIt, arrFin
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet ' use the necessary sheet
  Set wsDest = ws.Next 'use the necessary sheet (if it is OK, the code may clear all the sheet content and paste there)
  
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = ws.Range("A1:I" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionay
                                                  'which accepts only unique keys
  'load the dictionary:
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    'add the first concatenated columns (sep "|") as key and an array of the last 4 elements as item:
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3) & "|" & arr(i, 4) & "|" & arr(i, 5)) Then
       dict.Add arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3) & "|" & arr(i, 4) & "|" & arr(i, 5), _
                                                     Array(arr(i, 6), arr(i, 7), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 9))
    Else
        'change the last item elements with the actual iterated row, if its date is > existing:
        If arr(i, 6) > dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3) & "|" & arr(i, 4) & "|" & arr(i, 5))(0) Then
            dict(arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3) & "|" & arr(i, 4) & "|" & arr(i, 5)) = _
                                                     Array(arr(i, 6), arr(i, 7), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 9))
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  'redim the final array according to the dictionary number of keys:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
  
  'load the final array
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    k = k + 1 'increment the array row
    arrKey = Split(dict.keys()(i), "|") 'extract an array by splitting the key by its separator ("|")
    arrIt = dict.Items()(i)             'place here the item array (last 4 row columns)
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrKey): arrFin(k, j + 1) = arrKey(j): Next j 'load the elements extracted from key
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt): arrFin(k, j + UBound(arrKey) + 2) = arrIt(j): Next j 'load the elemnts extracted from item
  Next i
  
  'drop the processed array content, at once:
  wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
  MsgBox "Job done..."
End Sub


Okay, thank you for the help!

@Kitty Lila What do you mean by "Okay"? After three month... Did you find some time to test the code? If tested, doesn't it do what you need?
